# Don't check field if parameter is an empty string

Tags: sql

I want to do this

```
(s.Reference = @Reference or @Reference = '')
```

but I get an sql error saying unable to convert nvarchar to bigint.  What's going on there.  I just want to skip that query on the Refernce if the input parameter is an empty string.

Comment: What are the data types of the field and the input parameter?

Comment: Reference is a nvarchar(100) and so is the Param.  it seems that MsSql has a problem with the @reference = ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `SQL Server`, the best decision would be this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   s.Reference = @Reference
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   @Reference IS NULL
```

It will optimize one of the queries away and execute only the remaining one (using the index if needed).

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though Reference is a numeric field. In this case, you are probably looking to do:

```
(s.Reference = @Reference or @Reference is null)
```

When you put ='' into the test condition, you make an assumption that it's a string.